# PHP can only compare numbers, not strings

Tags: php

This must be super simple but for some reason I cannot figure it out. I use exec_shell to run a .sh that echo's a value at the end of the script. If the script echo's a numerical comparisons work fine, but if I echo a string like SomeName it does not work.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['CheckConnectionBtn'])){
 $output = shell_exec("script.sh");
 $_SESSION["CHECK"] = "$output";
}
?>
```

This works

```
<?php if ($output == 1) : ?>
```

This doesn't.

```
<?php if ($output == SomeName) : ?>
```

I also tried

```
<?php if ($output == "SomeName") : ?>
```

But this doesn't work either. The .sh outputs either 1 or SomeName without any quotations marks or anything.

Comment: `shell_exec` — Execute command via shell and return the complete output as a `string`

Comment: I guess the returned string value contains white spaces, namely line break `\n`. You should trim white spaces before comparison.

Comment: Trim the whitespaces or linebreaks from $output before comparison.